# Exporting MySQL DB to excel (Connection probleme)

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a table in MySQL DB and I want to export it to excel. I've tried a lot of source-codes but it seems like nothing work for me; it looks like I'm having a connection problem and it should be between my .php code and DB.

First, I'm using XMPP to host my DB(phpmyadmin) I can access it by typing localhost/phpmyadmin or localhost:80/phpmyadmin  I've created to DB one is called "test" and second is "gfdepot".well I m interested in the second one. In "gfdepot" DB I've 6 tables, and I'm interested in a table named "zone."

Well, currently I'm using eclipse IDE(with the .php extension installed) to script my website. All I want is to have a clickable button to export "zone" table to an Excel file. The clickable button works well, but the ".php" page doesn't work!
Whatever I try I always get the connection error.
Currently, I m trying this code below.

```html
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "root"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "gfdepot";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "zone"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

and this is what i get.

```html
" . mysql_error() . "
" . mysql_errno()); //select database $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:
" . mysql_error(). "
" . mysql_errno()); //execute query $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:
" . mysql_error(). "
" . mysql_errno()); $file_ending = "xls"; //header info for browser header("Content-Type: application/xls"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls"); header("Pragma: no-cache"); header("Expires: 0"); /*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/ //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word) $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) { echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t"; } print("\n"); //end of printing column names //start while loop to get data while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { $schema_insert = ""; for($j=0; $j
```

Well this is my first post here and I 'm not a programming expert and it's my first time trying a .php code, and tnx in advance

Comment: i would like to add that i've managed to show my table on a .jsp page

and this is connection's line
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gfdepot", "root", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your hostname to specify the port number

Eg. localhost:3306

Comment: 1- On xampp it shows 3306 for MySQL,
2- i'm hosting the .php file on eclipseIDE's tomcat server 7.0  (port:8070) and phpmyadmin is on xampp, xampp's Apache Serever port is 80 and MySQL's port is 3306,so i dont think they are on same server.
3- well i'm already using that DB on eclipse to login and to read informations from the DB,thats why i think it accept connection from external sources

Comment: Have u tried to just change the hostname and add 3306 to ur php hostname variable?

Comment: yea i've changed it to   $DB_Server = "localhost:3306";

but i'm getting same error,please check above i've edited my post and added error message that i get.

Comment: Is that your actual error in the update?. Doesn't show anything meaningful.

Comment: unfortunately that's what get everytime i try to run the .php file!  i'm just a beginner and i just copied that code from internet and pasted it on my .php file ,i don't know if i'm supposed to add something else